# Initial Network Connection Slows Over Time

Tags: networking, router, internet

I have a Linksys Velop MX4000 router. My network has 1 node with 10 devices connected. My internet speed appears healthy (ping: 19ms, down: 229 Mbps, up: 22 Mbps). Over time, my internet connection becomes basically unusable. It get's to the point where I can't load a popular website like Amazon or Yahoo Finance. This happens after roughly 3 days to one week. To resolve this issue, I restart my router, which works for a few days. It's very annoying. I'd like to resolve this issue once and for all.

My challenge is, I have no idea what the cause of this is. If it was the router, it seems like this should be solvable via a software update. It seems like it should've been resolved by now if it was software. Oddly, when this issue surfaces, it acts like it has problems during the initial connection to whatever site I'm accessing. As shown below, my packet loss rate seems high.

```
me@machine ~ % ping www.google.com
PING www.google.com (142.250.64.228): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 142.250.64.228: icmp_seq=0 ttl=110 time=52.177 ms
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
64 bytes from 142.250.64.228: icmp_seq=2 ttl=110 time=96.489 ms
64 bytes from 142.250.64.228: icmp_seq=3 ttl=110 time=60.100 ms
64 bytes from 142.250.64.228: icmp_seq=4 ttl=110 time=58.306 ms
64 bytes from 142.250.64.228: icmp_seq=5 ttl=110 time=58.820 ms
Request timeout for icmp_seq 6
64 bytes from 142.250.64.228: icmp_seq=7 ttl=110 time=92.409 ms
64 bytes from 142.250.64.228: icmp_seq=8 ttl=110 time=50.250 ms
64 bytes from 142.250.64.228: icmp_seq=9 ttl=110 time=49.565 ms
64 bytes from 142.250.64.228: icmp_seq=10 ttl=110 time=57.546 ms
64 bytes from 142.250.64.228: icmp_seq=11 ttl=110 time=57.610 ms
64 bytes from 142.250.64.228: icmp_seq=12 ttl=110 time=65.195 ms
64 bytes from 142.250.64.228: icmp_seq=13 ttl=110 time=59.214 ms
64 bytes from 142.250.64.228: icmp_seq=14 ttl=110 time=58.224 ms
64 bytes from 142.250.64.228: icmp_seq=15 ttl=110 time=57.917 ms
64 bytes from 142.250.64.228: icmp_seq=16 ttl=110 time=52.983 ms
64 bytes from 142.250.64.228: icmp_seq=17 ttl=110 time=52.727 ms
--- www.google.com ping statistics ---
18 packets transmitted, 16 packets received, 11.1% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 49.565/61.221/96.489/13.173 ms
```

How do I a) diagnose this sporadic issue and/or b) resolve it?

Comment: Little to go on here. (1) Update the firmware in your router (2) Try the computer in question on a totally different network (3) consider a replacement / spare router to test with.

Comment: last few times I've had an issue like this, I've needed to replace the router. if its a standard consumer-grade home internet access router, they usually only live about 3 years. YMMV.

Comment: Check for the wifi card. Maybe it has a problem. See if something is heating or not.